# Ngrx select doesn't trigger

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am starting to learn state management with ngrx and playing around with a tutorial.

Maybe i am losing my mind, but I don't know why the select you see below isn't triggering.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.store.dispatch(setName({ name: 'Hello World ' + Date.now() }));
    }, 10000);

    this.name$ = this.store
      .select((state) => state.name)
      .pipe(tap(console.log));
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bnnzzv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

it trigger's once with undefined, but shouldn't it fire on every dispatch?

Comment: Try this: `.select((state) => state.app.name)`

Comment: this works, tyvm! I am just wondering is the generic type in my constructor wrong? `constructor(private store: Store<AppState>)`

stackblitz is showing me an error that 'app' doesn't exist on type AppState,
it still works though